# cambiar app gratuita a pagada

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

App que desarrollé en Android Studio y la tengo en PlayStore.
La he mejorado y quiero que sea de pago. He sabido que una aplicacion gratis no puede hacerse de pago, a menos que se cambie el nombre del paquete com.
Lo hice y no encuentro en mi proyecto ninguna huella del nombre anterior, solo el nombre nuevo.
Al generar el .apk y subirla a PlayStore me dice que ese nombre de paquete ya existe y me menciona el nombre antiguo; es decir para google play es el mismo paquete de la app gratis.
Vale la pena mencionar que las mejoras y modificación de la app la hice trabajando sobre el mismo proyecto y al final le cambié el nombre de paquete.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Quite las firmas y los formalismos, ya que en este sitio no son necesarios.